# Passing HttpContext in a ActionBlock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library, httpcontext, tpl-dataflow

I am doing AzureAD implict flow for authenticating on a ASP.NET Core (2.2) api. For a specific reference to a library the application is in .net 4.8 but the api is hosted inside asp.net core.

The API makes a service to service call using the TPL dataflow blocks. The access token received when the UI(react) makes the request has got the roles and scopes and is stored inside `HttpContext` for downstream api calls (*OnBehalfOf flow*).

The `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` is `null` inside the pipeline. Outside of the pipeline I have access to the `HttpContext`. It looks to be really ugly to pass the context into every method call as a parameter.

Is there any other way to do this? I know I can use *Client Credential flow*, where I could configure the AD and use daemon app and get a token. But if I am stuck doing an *OnBehalfOf flow*, what could be the solution.

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.Authorization))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Header Not Found."));
        }

        var requestHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        var token = requestHeader.FirstOrDefault()?.Split(' ').Last();

        Request.HttpContext.Items.Add("tokenfordownstream", token); // retrieve from context for api to api calls

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

`Microsoft.Identity.Web` could not be installed because of a number of package downgrade. I think it is conflicting with binaries in `Microsoft.Identity.Client`

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
public class RiskPipelineFactory : IRiskPipelineFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public RiskPipelineFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; //httpContext is NOT null
    }   
    
    public IRiskPipeline Create()
    {
        var preLoaderAction = new ActionBlock<(pricingExercise, risks)>(LoadStep, loadOptions);
        return new RiskSlicePipeline(preLoaderAction);
        
        //I don't want to pass the httpContext here, because there are also other blocks that
        //gets stitched togther and many method calls, so it will be quite messy
        private async Task LoadStep((PricingExercise pricingExercise, Risks risks) input)
        {
            //HttpContext is null here, if _httpContextAccessor is not passed as a param        
            //do the other api call here for the sake of simplicity, but retrieving the access token will fail
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't pass the HttpContext to the action block. Pass the request's payload or any other data that may be needed in the message. The HttpContext refers to a specific request, which has probably ended by the time the block starts processing the message.

Comment: BTW to create a pipeline you need a TransformBlock or TransformManyBlock at least. An ActionBlock is typically used at the *end* of a pipeline. Blocks pass messages directly to any other block they're linked to through `LinkTo`.